# Clickable legend at Core Plot

Tags: swift, macos, core-plot, legend, clickable

I use Core Plot files to create my chart.
But CorePlot doesn't contain event "click on legend item".

How can I detect user's click on legend item ?

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, CPTPlotDataSource, CPTPieChartDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var graphView: CPTGraphHostingView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let graph = CPTXYGraph(frame: CGRect.zero)        
    var axes = graph.axisSet as! CPTXYAxisSet
    var lineStyle = CPTMutableLineStyle()
    lineStyle.lineWidth = 0
    axes.xAxis?.axisLineStyle = lineStyle
    axes.yAxis?.axisLineStyle = lineStyle


    var pie = CPTPieChart()
    pie.pieRadius = 100
    pie.dataSource = self
    pie.centerAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.18, y: 0.75)
    graph.add(pie)        

    var theLegend=CPTLegend(graph: graph)
    var legendFill=CPTFill(color: CPTColor.gray())
    theLegend.fill = legendFill
    var legendLineStyle = CPTMutableLineStyle()
    legendLineStyle.lineColor = CPTColor.white()
    theLegend.borderLineStyle = legendLineStyle
    theLegend.cornerRadius = 2.0
    theLegend.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0.1, height: 50)
    theLegend.numberOfColumns = 1

    graph.legend = theLegend
    graph.legendDisplacement = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 300)

    self.graphView.hostedGraph = graph
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Plot legends can have a delegate that is called on mouse down, mouse up, and/or selected (mouse down followed by mouse up on the same item) events. See the [CPTLegendDelegate protocol](http://core-plot.github.io/MacOS/protocol_c_p_t_legend_delegate-p.html) for details on the available methods. Unless you need some specific behavior not covered by the delegate, you don't need worry about the responder chain.

Answer (score 0):

If you dig into the source code for Core Plot, you can follow the inheritance chain of CPTLegend all the way up to CPTLayer:

https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/blob/master/framework/Source/CPTLegend.h
https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/blob/master/framework/Source/CPTBorderedLayer.h
https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/blob/master/framework/Source/CPTAnnotationHostLayer.h
https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/blob/master/framework/Source/CPTLayer.h

If you examine the header file for CPTLayer, it conforms to CPTResponder, and if you go to the source for CPTResponder:

https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/blob/master/framework/Source/CPTResponder.h

You will notice that there are two relevant methods among others:

-(BOOL)pointingDeviceDownEvent:(nonnull CPTNativeEvent *)event atPoint:(CGPoint)interactionPoint;

-(BOOL)pointingDeviceUpEvent:(nonnull CPTNativeEvent *)event atPoint:(CGPoint)interactionPoint;

What I think you can probably do is to subclass CPTLegend and override one or both methods depending on your needs to detect clicks.

Comment: pointingDeviceDownEvent and pointingDeviceUpEvent always return false.
How can I detect "legend" location and sizes? If legend will contains long words, this legend will be longer